# correct punctuation around the phrase "in conjuction with"?

Tags: punctuation

The Hiring Committee, in conjunction with the Headmaster, will make the final decision.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What does the research you've done into your question so far suggest the answer might be?

Comment: This precise usage (X, in conjunction with Y, verb/ed) is hard to track down in dictionaries and on the internet. The example 'The hotel, in conjunction with the wedding planner, prepared a sumptuous banquet.' can be found at [WritingTips](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=90YagPVhGZFA.html), but with the recommendation to use the less prolix 'The hotel and the wedding planner prepared a sumptuous banquet.' instead.